# Working from home - Need to share keyboard and mouse with home and work on vpn

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, kvm-switch

I have Work surface pro 3 (Windows 10) that is always on VPN and I have a windows 10 home computer, 1 BT keyboard + mouse and one monitor.

Basically when I work from home I would like to just use the same monitor and Bluetooth keyboard and mouse.

I know KVM switch but I'm trying to keep my small desk clutter free. I read about Syngery but they work as long as both computers are in the same network.

So with my work computer being on VPN, I don't think this solution will work.

Any other ideas? or is there a BT keyboard and mouse that can work with 2 computers? or is there anything such as Bluetooth KVM?

I saw this device on Amazon but not sure if this will work for my needs. 
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LV8U39I/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LV8U39I)

Comment: There are some keyboard (and mouse) that can sync to multiple devices. One such device (no affiliation with the device or brand besides I've heard of them in my research) - [Kanex Bluetooth Keyboard](http://www.kanex.com/keyboard) and something like [Logitech mouse](https://www.logitech.com/en-au/product/m720-triathlon) that allows multiple bluetooth connection and a button to switch between the multiple devices.

Comment: What about remote desktop connection from your work pc to your home one.  This way you use the same monitor and control both of them with the same keyboard and mouse.

Comment: I'm a little confused about this question.  If you're working from home and accessing a computer at work, there is no kind of local device sharing that will work.  You need some form of remote access, like Máté Juhász describes.